# How to calculate Revelle factor using only pH, DIC and TAlk for seawater?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, water, ph

I have the temperature, salinity, $\mathrm{pH},$ dissolved inorganic carbon (DIC) and total alkalinity (TAlk) values for an estuarine water sample. I want to calculate the [Revelle factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelle_factor).

The Revelle factor can be calculated from the partial pressure of $\ce{CO2}$ and DIC. But I don't have the value for partial pressure of $\ce{CO2}.$ I want to know whether it is possible to calculate Revelle factor using $\mathrm{pH}$, DIC and Talk values. And if it is possible then I want to know how to do it.

Comment: Use CO2SYS, it's a multi platform which links together the relevant equilibrium equations of the carbonate system.
Available at: https://cdiac.ess-dive.lbl.gov/ftp/co2sys/